# Is there an adjective that means 'fruit-like'?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

**Is there a word for *fruit-like* that could be uttered by an aristocratic gentleman of the 18<sup>th</sup> Century in a club such as *[Boodle's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boodle%27s)* without sounding anachronous or ill-befitting of his class?**

Before anyone mentions it, I have looked at '[fruitlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fruitlike)', but, due to its lack of use pre-1850 ([Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fruitlike&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfruitlike%3B%2Cc0)) and the fact it is being corrected by my spell-checker due to its rarity, I am discounting it.

> #### Adjective
>
> **fruitlike** ‎(comparative more fruitlike, superlative most fruitlike)
>
> 1. Resembling fruit.
>
>    - *The chewing gum had a fruitlike fragrance.*

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fruitlike))

I have also looked at *fruity* but, in my setting, it seems slightly out-of-place, despite it being used at the time†.

> #### Adjective
>
> **fruity** ‎(comparative fruitier, superlative fruitiest)
>
> 1. containing fruit or fruit flavouring
> 2. similar to fruit or tasting of fruit
> 3. ([informal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#informal)) mad, crazy
> 4. ([informal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#informal), derogatory, LGBT, of a male) effeminate or otherwise flamboyant or homosexual
> 5. (Britain, [informal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#informal)) sexually suggestive.
>
>    - *His text message was filled with fruity language.*

The sentence into which my word needs to fit is as follows:

> By George! doesn't that painting render his head so dreadfully **[fruity]**

---

† It was used at the time, but I am unsure as to with which meaning; № 3, 4, 5 would certainly not fit.

> [**fruity** (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fruity&allowed_in_frame=0)
>   1650s, from [fruit](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fruit&allowed_in_frame=0) + [-y](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-y&allowed_in_frame=0) (2). Related: *Fruitiness*.

([Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fruity&allowed_in_frame=0))

<sup>The example sentence doesn't need to be too rigid; if you can find a good word, don't let the sentence stop you!</sup>

Comment: What kind of fruit did you have in mind? Would something like pear-shaped work?

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD Any sort of fruit is acceptable, but *pear-shaped* wouldn't work as it is too specific, I would prefer it to cover *all* fruit.

Comment: So you're saying the character depicted in the painting has a  fruity head? And your not using definitions 3-5? I'm having a hard time envisioning the context

Comment: @StuW More specifically, I'm looking for a replacement for *similar to fruit*.

Comment: I think your quest will be fruitless. You want a word to describe the shape or look of all fruit, and given the wide variety of fruit, that's not possible. *Fruity* applies widely for aroma or taste, likely because of the presence of fructose, but I don't see how you'll find one word to compare an element of a portrait to apples, grapes, papayas, and pineapples. You could try *Doesn't his portrait render his neck **fructiverous**?*, as though his neck was bearing his head as fruit, but I can't conjure an image for that.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on the particular qualities of fruit you wish to compare this head with. Given it’s a painting we’ve really just got shape and color and as others have mentioned all fruit do not have similar shapes or colors. Maybe if we stretch we could get to ripeness and squishiness.

Comment: ... pear-shaped?

Comment: Fruitish [in what way](http://www.healthandlovepage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Glycemic-Load.jpg)? And that doesn't have avocado.

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that aristocratic gentlemen, and gentlewomen, of the 18th Century, in England, weren't eating much fruit.  Cf.  Elizabeth Gaskell's *Cranford*: "When oranges came in, a curious proceeding was gone through. Miss Jenkyns did not like to cut the fruit, for, as she observed, the juice all ran out nobody knew where, sucking [only I think she used some more recondite word] was in fact the only way of enjoying oranges; but then there was the unpleasant association with a ceremony frequently gone through by little babies; and so, after dessert, in orange season, ...

Comment: ... Miss Jenkyns and Miss Matty used to rise up, possess themselves each of an orange in silence, and withdraw to the privacy of their own rooms to indulge in sucking oranges.”  That was published in 1851.  Oranges were a special treat.  A century earlier, I doubt anyone was eating any tropical fruit in the British Isles yet.  So we need to figure out what fruit they were eating.  I will guess: apples, pears, quinces, plums, maybe strawberries -- not sure, berries.  I think there is an adjective that means *like an apple*, starts with *pomm*.

Comment: The example sentence is actually quite important here -- we need to know what you're describing, and which attributes are important to you.  Fruit could be juicy, sweet, tart, round, pear-shaped, brightly colored, etc.  Maybe *luscious* but it really depends on the noun you're going to modify.

Comment: Is there some reason why you cannot use a descriptive propositional phrase instead of an adjective here? So for example, “The chewing gum had *the fragrance of fruit.”*  That seems more authentic to the period than pulling out some abstruse term unknown or at least unused by most native speakers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Fructiform* appears to exist as an obscure word for "having the form of a fruit" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fructiform).  My Collins dictionary doesn't list it, and I can't find any further details of how long it has been in use.

Comment: I like that! It has a rather frivolous air! Can you know any further use though? I have vaguely heard of it. Perhaps Ngrams can tell us something?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I couldn't get anything out of ngram.  Google books shows a few examples from the early 19th century, but none from the 18th.

Comment: That's not great for _my_ setting but it's good anyway.

Comment: From [the full OED:](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/75042) **fructiform** - *Having the form of a fruit.* Theor first (and *only!* :) citation is **1816**   Sir J. Sinclair in Monthly Mag. XLII. 298   *The fructiform productions which were found upon the same stalks often remained fixed together.*

Answer (score 0):

***Fructiferous*** maybe? (Bearing or producing fruit, OED)