# Is there an adjective that means 'stick-like'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Using the same setting as this question: [Is there an adjective that means 'fruit-like'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360076/is-there-an-adjective-that-means-fruit-like) (the setting isn't paramount) I would like to know if there is an appropriately 'posh' word for '*stick-like*'.

**Is there a word for *stick-like* that could be uttered by an aristocratic gentleman of the 18<sup>th</sup> Century in a club such as *[Boodle's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boodle%27s)* without sounding anachronous or ill-befitting of his class?**

The only word I can find is *[sticky](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sticky)* but it is too connected to the age-old joke:

> What's brown and sticky?   A stick! / Poo!

The use of adjective *sticky* also makes the word *sticky* useless. ([Etymologically, they are connected](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stick&allowed_in_frame=0))

**Obligatory Example Sentence:**

> My dear fellow, let me question you thus: *what is brown and* **[sticky]**?   A stick!

<sup>Obviously, this ruins the joke</sup>

Is there a suitable adjective like '*stick-like*'?

Comment: [*Twiggy*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=twiggy&biw=1106&bih=811&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOqr_9vcnQAhWnJcAKHV-gCKMQ_AUIBigB), perhaps?

Comment: Q. What's brown and sticky? A. [This](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=sticky+toffee+pudding). Yum!

Comment: "[rodlike](http://www.yourdictionary.com/rodlike)" ... ?

Comment: Google Books cites over a thousand written instances of [**stick-like** object,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stick-like+object%22) for example. So why do you need a "stick-like-like" word? Just use the first one you obviously thought of when writing this question.

Answer (score 1):

The *OED* attests to the following:

- baculine, bacillifrom. From the Latin *baculus* (staff, stick)
- hastiform. From the Latin *hastile* (spear, staff, or stick)
- virgate. From the Latin *virga* (rod, staff, or stick)

There is also the Latin word *lituus*, adopted into English, which means a wand used as a badge of office by Roman augurs. Feel free to make an adjectival if you can. Perhaps *lituual*.

Comment: I think it would be *litual.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm not sure I can take you litually. Perhaps *lituous* after *vacuous*.

Answer (score 0):

The OED has the nonce-word ***stickish***; its one attestation is close to the right time period:

> *nonce-wd*.
>   Something of a stick (cf. stick n.1 12b).
>
> 1810   Scott Let.
>   30 Jan. in J. G. Lockhart Mem. Life Scott (1837) II. vii. 271
>   Malcolm de Grey was tolerable but **stickish**.

"ˈstickish, adj." OED Online. Oxford University Press, September 2016.